# Android dynamic listView: removing items that are not displayed from ListView adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter, dynamic-data, baseadapter

I'm going to implement a dynamic ListView: By spending little time, ListView will populate more items from a local file when you are scrolling downward.I used technique like this to implement such dynamic list:http://mobile.dzone.com/news/android-tutorial-dynamicaly
**Problem:** Number of Items to be displayed is too large. So if I just keep adding them to data source of ListView Adapter, data source will consume too much memory and finally it will lead to application crash by scrolling more and more.

**Question**: How can I remove some of items that are not displayed from datasource  of ListView such that user do not get noticed? 
It is not important that user need to wait while scrolling up/down for fetching data.

Comment: Just a quick question, how sure are you that increasing `List` size is causing your high memory usage? A common issue on high memory consumption is inflating new view for each row without re-using `convert view`. How large is the size of your List when it crashes?

Comment: The problem is not about reusing Views, problem is something like reusing memory for datasource list.

Comment: allow me to have a look on your `getView()` method?

Comment: i did not implemented yet! i'm just wondering how to do that. Normally i use an ArrayList passed to adapter and use it inside getView methods.But i think it is not suitable for this type of implementation.

Comment: in normal cases you wouldn't need to worry about size of `List`, if you use chatting app such as Whatsapp, you should see that it has no problem loading few hundred items to a List using ListView, there is nothing to worry yet, unless your size goes up to thousands..

Comment: i got large text segment like paragraphs of a book. so i need to worry about this! :)

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I have a similar problem reading large XML.  I need to release memory of object that are not visible in listview.

Answer (score 0):

when you are using listview using base adaptor then adaptor will automatically get called whenever user perform scroll and auto destroy unseen elements.

Comment: I know that, but ListView only destory/reuse View Items not data elements attached to adapter. My problems is about reusing datasource items.